# Accessing Global Variable in function c++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

I have a very basic doubt. From the code below , I have declared Board[ ][ ] as a global char array. I would like to initialize the array in a function called `init_board()`. But the compiler returns

`In function void init_board():` 
`expected primary-expression before '{' token` 
`expected ;' before '{' token`

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

//global variables---------------
char Board[2][2];

//function declarations----------
void init_board();

int main(void)
{
init_board();

 for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
 { 
 for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
 {
  cout<<Board[i][j]<<" ";
 }
  cout<<"\n";
 }

getch();
}

void init_board()
{
Board[2][2] = {{'a','b'},{'c','d'}}; 
}
```

What is the basic error I am making...please point out !!

Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with globals.  It has to do with initializers.

Comment: `Board[2][2]` is out of range. Since `Board` has two row and two columns, only `0` and `1` are legal row/column values.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I cant see where I am over shooting range... i have 2 elements in 2 rows in `Board[2][2] = {{'a','b'},{'c','d'}};`

Comment: Right, so the valid entries are `Board[0][0]`, `Board[0][1]`, `Board[1][[0]`, and `Board[1][1]` -- that makes four, two by two. Your code attempts to assign a value to `Board[2][2]` (since that's what's on the left hand side of the `=`) -- but there is no `Board[2][2]`. (And even if there was, it would be a single character, not an array. `Board` is the array.) I think you're somehow imagining that the fact that there's an array on the right hand side of the equals sign will somehow make the thing on the left hand side into an array. But that's not how `=` works.

Comment: `Board[0][0] = 'a';`, for example, would be fine. `Board[0][0]` is a character entry in the array and `'a'` is one of the values it can take.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz : my bad! you are absolutely correct ! It just struck me! that is one stupid mistake I have made.... thanx !!! :D :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initializer syntax can be used only while declaring the array, i.e.

```
char board[2][2] = {{'a', 'b'}, {'c', 'd'}};
```

In all other cases, you need to browse through the array elements and set them.

Answer (score 0):

You are indexing Board[2][2] in init_board() you are indexing out-of-bound of the specified size of the array i.e. you have specified that the array is 2 rows and 2 columns but you are indexing into element 3 (indexing starts at 0 in C/C++ and a few other languages).
You can initialise the array at compile time at the top of the file where you have declared it:

```
char Board[2][2] = {{'a','b'},{'c','d'}};
```

Or you can initialise each element individually as others have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
void init_board()
{
Board = {{'a','b'},{'c','d'}};
}
```

That sould fix it...
When you use
Board[2][2] you are only reffering to the one char in the position [2][2]. So that means you would be adding a, b, c and d to only one bite of the Board